# Appium CodeceptJS - Mock sound recording - Android

Tags: testing, mocking, appium, codeceptjs, sound-recognition

I've been automating testing of mobile apps for a year now, but it's my first time, that a part of app records users' voice (it's actually a 3-step process, first recording of "silence" to calibrate to the background noise, second a prolonged "aaaaaah", and third deep breathing exercise to measure lung capacity).

I use CodeceptJS with Appium and an Android emulator.

I can't seem to find any documentation on how it's possible to mock a sound recording, nor a succinct answer that it cannot be done.

Quite new to SO as well, so I hope this question fits the bill.

How do I mock sound recordings and where do I find documentation for it?

Comment: Seems like it's not possible yet...